# Shell expansion

Tags: bash, shell

I have a question about how shell expands names in any directory/folder. Let's imagine we have two files called Docker.dmg and Docker (1).dmg (note the escape).

If I'd want to check if I have the file with the parentheses, I'd run a `ls -la Docker\ [\(0-9\)]*` and it'll show me the file (at least works in my Mac). The thing I'm not really understanding is why it doesn't work when I explicitly put the name like this:

```
ls -la Docker\ [\(0-9\)]\.dmg
```

If I understand correctly how Regex work and how shell expansion works, the latter should work fine as I'm escaping every metacharacter as the name have multiple of these.

Like always, thank you.

Comment: (1) POSIX-family shells use fnmatch patterns, not regular expressions, for globbing. (2) For questions that aren't specifically about writing code, see [unix.se] or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: (3) your pattern _requires_ a space to be present in the filename; `Docker.dmg` has no space.

Comment: (4) Your pattern requires _exactly one_ character inside set of `(`, `)`, and digits between 0 and 9 to be present.

Comment: If you were to enable extended globbing syntax (`shopt -s extglob`) and your shell _really is_ bash, think about `ls -la Docker?(\ (+([[:digit:]]))).dmg`. See https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pattern#extended_pattern_language for more details.

Comment: Coming back to why the original code didn't work, though: A character class matches only _exactly one_ character unless modified. So `[\(0-9\)]` will match `(` _or_ `)` _or_ `0` _or_ `1` _or_ `2`  etc., but it won't match `(1)` because that's three characters and the expression is written for only one.